# PHP CURL not always returning the same data

Tags: php, curl

I have this CURL function:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
```

This is the URL i'm accessing:
http://dyproperties.bm/realty/index.php?action=listingview&listingID=217

If i access the URL in a single process, I get back the correct HTML

When I try and parse a bunch of URLS from an Array, every page returns a 404 type page.  I can't seem to figure out the problem, if i run CURL from the linux command line, I get the 404 page, if i use file_get_contents instead from a single process, I get the correct data, if i use file_get_contents from an array of URLS, every URL returns a 404 type page, even if i die() after the first one is parse, i'm stumped...

any help?

Comment: are you using curl_init inside the loop?

Comment: we are, we crawl about 2 dozen other sites with this code and all come back fine, its just this one site that is the problem, the code needs a rework from the current version